# CURL POST and PUT request is not working?

Tags: node.js, json, curl

**I am learning JSON and new to backend devlopment
       i had ran my "server.js" file by npm start command .
        when i ran the curl post and put command it is giving error.
       I can't figure out what's the mistake in my code.
        I'm using windows 10 CMD

```
    this is my server file named -"server.js"
```

Please help me in figuring out the error **

//  NAME -server.js

```
const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
let profile = {
    username: 'azat',
    email: '[reducted]',
    url: 'http://azat.co'
}
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    res.send(profile)
})
app.post('/profile', (req, res) => {
    profile = req.body
    console.log('created', profile)
    res.sendStatus(201)
})
app.put('/profile', (req, res) => {
    Object.assign(profile, req.body)
    console.log('updated', profile)
    res.sendStatus(204)
})
app.delete('/profile', (req, res) => {
    profile = {}
    console.log('deleted', profile)
    res.sendStatus(204)
})

app.listen(3000)
```

```
   // My CURL command


    curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d '{"first_name":"Azat","last_name":"khan"}'  "http://localhost:3000/profile"
```

//      the error on sever side is

```
       SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Users\login\Desktop\Learn\JSON\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)
    at parse (C:\Users\login\Desktop\Learn\JSON\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
    at C:\Users\login\Desktop\Learn\JSON\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\login\Desktop\Learn\JSON\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (C:\Users\login\Desktop\Learn\JSON\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\login\Desktop\Learn\JSON\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:198:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1142:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
```

Comment: It is most likely a problem of malformed json being sent to `bodyParser.json()` on your POST/PUT request

Comment: Maybe try: `curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "{\"first_name\":\"Azat\",\"last_name\":\"khan\"}"  http://localhost:3000/profile` . I suspect it's an issue with the single quotes in your terminal maybe.

Comment: @Matt Harrison Thanks a lot ,it works .Can u please tell me how to solve this single quote problem in my terminal